# Как сохранять store в LocalStorage при обновлении страницы?

Tags: reactjs, redux, localstorage

С помощью каких middleware это реализуется? И по какому принципу? 
Не могу понять.

Сейчас у меня подключены thunk, logger.

```
 ../src/store/configureStore.js

 import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
 import { rootReducer } from "../reducers";
 import logger from 'redux-logger'
 import thunk from  'redux-thunk'

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));
```

Answer (score 1):

Выбирайте какой нравится:

[redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist)

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web and AsyncStorage for react-native

import rootReducer from './reducers'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export default () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { store, persistor }
}
```

[redux-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-localstorage)

```
import {compose, createStore} from 'redux';
import persistState from 'redux-localstorage'

const enhancer = compose(
  /* [middlewares] */,
  persistState(/*paths, config*/),
)

const store = createStore(/*reducer, [initialState]*/, enhancer)
```